# How to setup Eclipse for a bjam ( boost.build ) project

Tags: eclipse, boost

I am an eclipse newbie. I have a C++ project that is compiled with bjam and has jamfiles for the same. Eclipse has a lot of support for Makefile based C++ projects I believe. How do I get Eclipse to work smoothly for the bjam based C++ project ?

Answer (score 2):

Edit Project Properties -> C/C++ Build:

- uncheck "Use default build command" and enter bjam as build command.
- uncheck generates "Make automatically".

In the Behaviour tab you can also specify details like debug and release build and how to clean your project.